# How to create an aggregate Bloc to set up loading data in stages?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have this calendar app, that has to load a lot of data (events to put on the calendar) from an external API. This takes a while, and I want to give feedback to the user what the app is doing while they are waiting for the complete data to arrive. So what I did up until now is have a bloc, that does the loading of all the events for the calendar, and when all have been fetched, I emit a state to the Widget (which is basically a BlocBuilder) saying that all is loaded.

Now how could I split this up in more granular BLocs? So each category of calendar event can be fetched separately through the API (as well as all at once like I do it now). So I was thinking of creating a number of ChildBlocs, and one Aggregatorbloc. The AggregatorBlock would listen to all its ChildBlocs, and whenever one of these ChildBlocs received its data from the API, it would pass it on to the Aggregator and the calendar would be updated with the new events. This way all children could query the API in parallel, and the calendar could be updated whenever one of the children has data ready. The calendar Widget would only need to listen to the AggregatorBloc, and all ChildBlocs could be shielded from the outside through the AggregatorBloc.

So in the end, the user would get an empty calendar at first, and a progressbar at the bottom that fills up until all children have given their data. Everytime one of the ChildBlocs gives it data to the AggregatorBloc, it would fill in the Calendar with the events received from ChildBloc, and fill some part of the progressbar.

Is this a reasonable architecture? Or should I just use all the different Child blocs in my widgets, and drop the idea of the AggregatorBloc? I tried to get something to work with Streams and Sinks, but I couldn't get it to work correctly, and then I read some documentation ([here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication)) which mentioned explicitly that you should **not** do this.

How should I proceed? Any tips?

Edit:
If I do it like this, wouldn't that make the calls to the API go one by one, instead of in parallel?

```
emit(state.copyWith(
  newStatus: UserCalendarMainPageEventDetailsStateEnum.startLoadingAll,
));
var birthdays = await _remoteApi.fetchBirthdays();
progress += 1;
emit(state.copyWith(
  newStatus: UserCalendarMainPageEventDetailsStateEnum.progress,
  progressCount: progress
));
var holidays = await _remoteApi.fetchHolidays();
progress += 1;
emit(state.copyWith(
  newStatus: UserCalendarMainPageEventDetailsStateEnum.progress,
  progressCount: progress
));
}
```

Comment: why not to emit a "progress" state each time you fetch new data from your multiple API data sources?

Comment: See edit. Wouldn't that make it do the fetching one by one, instead of all in parallel?

Comment: check `Future.wait`, the docs say: "Waits for multiple futures to complete and collects their results.

Returns a future which will complete once all the provided futures have completed, either with their results, or with an error if any of the provided futures fail."

Comment: At the moment I did the `Future.wait` thing, with all of my sub API calls in a list. This does not give me the option to get a progressBar to follow the progress.. But I can work with it now. Thanks for the tip.